# Magento Rest Api in PowerAutomate error

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have 2 poweautomate cloud flows for integrating magento to some other systems. The first one is working correctly and I am getting the items/produts based on the search criteria I am passing.

Initially in a step I am getting the admin token
[image]

In the next steps i am getting the items i want, as shown in the picture. Everything is working correctly
[image]

In another flow i am doing the same steps to get some orders (the steps shown in the picture), but the authentication isn't working (i tested it in postman and is working)

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated